# Add linear gradient over dynamic background-image in Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following html code but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to add a linear gradient over a dynamic background image url using Angular 6.

```
<header *ngIf="user?.backgroundPhotoUrl != null && user?.backgroundPhotoUrl !== ''"
    [style.background-image]="'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('+ user?.backgroundPhotoUrl +')'">
```

But it just comes back blank. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the browser's console. Likely it will contain the following Angular warning:

WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),.... (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

If this is the case, Angular will simply have removed your style rule because the Angular team decided that any custom style binding may potentially be harmful i.e. when the value would be derived from user input.

You will have to declare your bounded style rule as save, by wrapping that value like this:

```
<header [style]="headerStyle"> ...</header>

get headerStyle() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
      ' background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)),  url(' + this.backgroundPhotoUrl + '); '
    );
}
```

this.sanitizer is an injected [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

Comment: cv3HeaderStyle() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
      `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(${this.user.backgroundPhotoUrl})`
    );
  }